# Possible to guard columns for updates only in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

You have the `$fillable` and `$guarded` to protect from mass assignment. But how do I guard certain db-columns so that it's impossible to update them?

Comment: Impossible to update them only via mass assignment or also via setting them directly? (`$model->foo = 'bar'`)

Comment: Ofcourse it would be a solution to manually set which fields to update in the controller. Would be sweet if there was a way for mass assignment too.

Comment: No I'm asking if setting them manually should be possible. In other words should the protection only be for mass assignment or for every possible way to set a model attribute?

Comment: I'm thinking of mass assignment here

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `isFillable()` in your model and use the `exists` property to determine if the model is already in the database or not (if you're creating or updating). Also you're going to need another property to configure those attributes. Let's call it `$guardedForUpdate`:

```
protected $guarded = ['foo'];
protected $guardedForUpdate = ['bar'];

public function isGuardedForUpdate($key){
    return in_array($key, $this->guardedForUpdate) || $this->guardedForUpdate == array('*');
}

public function isFillable($key){
    if($this->exists && $this->isGuardedForUpdate($key)){
        return false;
    }
    return parent::isFillable($key);
}
```

`foo` still won't be mass assigned in any case. Whereas `bar` is mass assignable when creating a new model but not when updating one.

Comment: Looks very promising. I will give it a try!